# fetch/axios returning undefined (only during imports) when using yield/sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator, redux-saga

I've looked at similar questions and most issues were because a return was missing.

I'm getting an `undefined` result back from my `yield call` **only if the function I'm calling is being imported**.

What am I missing ?

**The following is not working**

// Saga.ts

```
import { takeLatest, all, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import { fetchAPI } from 'utils/routes/api'; // why does importing it affect it
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

export function* fetchSaga(action: Action<{ Id: string }>) {
  yield put(actions.fetchId.request());

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const { data, error } = yield call(fetchAPI, "url"); // the logs in the fetchAPI method are not being fired
  // My tests fail on the above because the return of the above statement is undefined so cannot 
  // de-structure data or error
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (data) {
    yield put(actions.fetchId.success(data));
  } else {
    yield put(actions.fetchId.failure(error));
  }
}
```

**However, if I copy/paste the fetchAPI into the Saga file it works as expected**

**The following is working**

// Saga.ts

```
import { takeLatest, all, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
// import { fetchAPI } from 'utils/routes/api'; // commented, move implementation here

export const fetchAPI = async (endpoint: string, params: any = {}) => {
  console.log("DOES THIS LOG HIT"); // prints to the console (not in the imported function)
  return await axios
    .get(`${endpoint}`, { params, withCredentials: true })
    .then((res) => ({ data: res.data }))
    .catch((error) => ({ error }));
}

export function* fetchSaga(action: Action<{ Id: string }>) {
  yield put(actions.fetchId.request());
 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // works as expected
  const { data, error } = yield call(fetchAPI, "url");
  // Tests do not fail as the data is returned above
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (data) {
    yield put(actions.fetchId.success(data));
  } else {
    yield put(actions.fetchId.failure(error));
  }
}
```

The fetchAPI method is the exact same in both cases; in the failing case, the only difference it is being imported.

Please advise

Comment: Can you check whether you've successfully imported the function? ie, do `console.log(fetchAPI)` after the import statement.

Comment: Include the contents of `utils/routes/api` in your question. It's probably being exported or imported wrongly

Comment: I have console.log(fetchAPI) previously and I received data so I knew it was being imported because running the application works as intended also, but I have carefully read the log of fetchAPI and saw it was a mocked function which tells me Jest is mocking them out somewhere, at least now I know why ! thanks again